# Creature that can sleep/hibernate under the water for a very long time

Tags: creature-design, gods, sea-creatures, amphibian

There's a god that can morph into any creature he wants. He wanted to sleep for a very long time (like centuries), and found a perfect place at the bottom of a lake that is connected to the open sea. Now, **what kind of creature would be suitable for him to morph into?**

**Requirements:**

- It has to be a big-sized creature (like a megalodon).
- It should be similar to an existent (or extinct) real creature, though it can be modified (e.g. he can be inmortal because he's a god).
- If possible, based on a creature that hibernates.
- I want it to lay at the bottom of the lake, but I didn't want it to have any kind of shell.

**Bonus:** When he wakes up, he's going to fight another kraken-like god. So I would prefer if he doesn't have to morph again just for the fight.

Comment: no big creature can survive centuries of no nutrition. What are you exactly looking for, and what researches have you done?

Comment: The great ol' Cthulhu comes to mind. Big, hibernating god under the sea

Comment: Gods typically have their own rules and are not limited by nature, so the answer would normally be "whatever you like". Also, the list of criteria that you give do not really give too much wiggle room (big like a megalodon and similar to an actual creature? --> a megalodon)

Comment: I know that no big creature can survive that long, that's why I added the example of _"is inmortal because he's a god"_. I was hoping that maybe there's some animal that could be rescaled to fit the requirements. Like some kind of abyssal animal, but I didn't find any who actually hibernates.

Comment: Why don't you do a hybrid? Choose an animal you like that hibernates, that is big, that has no shell and so on and combine them.

Comment: Okay, so coudn't it be some kind of giant snake or crocodile? They both can stay dormant for long periods of time, slowing their metabolism, etc. I think both of them fulfil my requirements. Should I close the question or let someone answer?

Comment: @Raditz_35 That should be an answer. If you answer in a comment, someone else can put what you said into an answer and get +15 for acceptance plus however many upvotes they get.

Comment: @JohnLocke If it makes them happy, I approve of someone "stealing" that idea. I really don't care. But I'm not posting it as an answer because I don't know if this is even within the scope of the question. It's also more of a different way to look at the problem than an answer. The question is purely opinion based which keeps me from answering it. I know this is a grey area, but I think explaining to the op the vast possibilities of answering this question that they might not realize or have explored so far could potentially lead to this being an acceptable question at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a god and assuming you can bend nature's rules to some extent, you could use some adaptation of a [diving bell spider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diving_bell_spider), as they can sleep underwater yet aren't fully aquatic. If you use this as a base and then stretch the time scale to whatever massive proportions you're considering, you could have it sleeping rather than hibernating, waking up for air after a long period.

The wood frog previously mention would also be a good candidate, but a spider/spider-like creature would give you a different kraken-fighting dynamic.

Comment: That's a good answer. I don't like the frog idea because of the lack of fighting skills and the fact that the lake should completly froze for that kind of hibernation. I had no idea this spiders existed, but as I stated in the question, he can be sleeping, not only hibernating.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you handwave pretty much everything, hibernation just isn't a realistic way to survive for centuries. Many hibernators are built to only last a few months during winter, and most aquatic critters are [ectotherms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ectotherm) which [cannot truly hibernate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernation#Dormancy_in_ectotherms) without a very stable [hibernaculum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernaculum_(zoology)), since they have a serious risk of freezing to death or asphyxiating.

However, freezing to death is actually your best option here.

---

Behold the mighty [wood frog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wood_frog), master of cryogenics and resurrection:

[image: Small brown frog on white background]

As I said before, ectotherms need a climate-controlled hibernaculum in order to regulate body temperature and oxygen, and many frogs will [burrow into the ground or wallow in the bottom of a pond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frog#Torpor) in order to [wait out the winter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overwintering). However, some frogs are able to survive the winter by being partially frozen, such as the wood frog.

In order to [survive the freezing](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-do-frogs-survive-wint/), these frogs pump glucose through their bloodstream in order to protect their organs and blood cells from bursting as ice crystals form in their bodies. In this partially-frozen state, the frogs do not breath, their hearts do not beat, and their metabolism halts. Once their hibernaculum returns to above-freezing temperatures, they thaw and hop away like nothing happened.

So, your slumbering God simply needs to be a particularly resilient frog, and must find a lake that will be frozen for as long as it needs to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Frogs can hibernate, so he could be a giant frog. You can handwave making him giant because he's a god or you can combine him with another large animal like a crocodile. That has the bonus of making him ferocious so that he can fight the other god. You can handwave the nutrition issue because he's a god.